# Why isn't my rotation smooth?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

I'm currently working on a twin stick shooter but I encountered a problem when I rotate my player. The rotation snaps to right angles. I'm guessing it's a problem, due to the value that the joystick gives me back. [Here is a screen recording, via Giphy](http://giphy.com/gifs/26xBDN92QocLy84AU).

How do I go about fixing this problem?

This is my code:

```
 void FixedUpdate()
{

    float hR = gamepad.GetStick_R().X;
    float vR = gamepad.GetStick_R().Y;

    float lastHR = hR;
    float lastVR = vR;
    // This part was added recently in the hope of smoothing the rotation
    float lerpHr = Mathf.Lerp(lastHR, hR, Time.deltaTime * speedRotation);
    float lerpVr = Mathf.Lerp(lastVR, vR, Time.deltaTime * speedRotation);

    PlayerRotation(lerpHr, lerpVr);
}

void PlayerRotation(float h, float v)
{
    rotation.Set(h, 0f, v);

    if (rotation != Vector3.zero)
    {
        currentRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rotation);
        playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(currentRotation);
        lastRotation = currentRotation;
    }
    else
        playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(lastRotation);
}
```

I also tried two other ways, but each time, I got the same results. I tried every way I could think of, with these lines of code. I don't know where else to look.

```
// Attempt Two
playerRigidbody.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(p
    layerRigidbody.transform.rotation, currentRotation, Time.time * speedRotation);

// Attempt Three
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Atan2(v, h) * 180 / Mathf.PI, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity uses an axial dead zone this causes the joystick to "snap" at 90 degrees (up, down, left, right). What you need is a radial dead zone.

First, you need to go into the Unity Input Manager and set the dead zone ("dead") value to zero (0), to disable their axial dead zone.

[image: Under "Input Manager" > "Axes", you have to set the "Dead" value to 0 for every axes where you do not want snapping.]

Then, do your own radial dead zone:

```
float hR = gamepad.GetStick_R().X;
float vR = gamepad.GetStick_R().Y;

float deadzone_squared = 0.1f * 0.1f;

// calculate and compare magnitude squared (skip the square root)
if((hR * hR + vR * vR) < deadzone_squared)
{
  hR = 0;
  vR = 0;
}
```

This will create a deadzone that is a circle, rather than a cross.

Comment: [This article from gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/JoshSutphin/20130416/190541/Doing_Thumbstick_Dead_Zones_Right.php) is very useful in understanding this.

Comment: Thanks, both of you! I saw the article before but I though that was not my problem. I get it now.